# Can we have an injective function that goes from $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This function needs to be able to take both negative numbers , only one or non negative numbers, and find an image. Also have an inverse.
I'm trying to map 2D coordinate plane to a 1D.
I have seen examples for $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R \to  \Bbb R$, that will take the decimal places of each number. But can't seem to find one from $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$? Or the other way around.

Ok I think I may have one that fits my purpose:

f(x,y)=x but with the following restrictions:
you take values of x that have a difference say 100. This difference is also added to y, to find a different pair.
Then take the subset of the origin selected and the image for each x taken.

For example you can use these pairs:
(100,200)->100

(0,100)->0

(-100,0)->-100

(-200,-100)->-200

Comment: $Z\times Z\to N\times N\to N\to Z$

Comment: a composite function? how would this be?

Comment: $(a,b)\mapsto 2^a3^b$ for $a, b\ge 0.$ Next $(a, b)\mapsto 5^a7^{-b}$ for $a\ge 0, b\le 0.$ Then take the next to primes and continue.

Comment: An element of of  ZxZ is a string, in programmers' terminlogy, made up of symbols 0,1,...9, a comma and  also minus signs. That is, a string making use of 12 symbols. Regard it as representing an integer in base 12  number system, and that gives the map to Z which will be injective.

Comment: @PVanchinathan yes that is a simple solution exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: I think @AlvinL is referencing the very famous proof that the rationals are countable using $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, see here : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.